# What is wrong in this simple Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
SRC_VAR = test string for variable manipulation.

TEST1_VAR = $(subset for,foo,${SRC_VAR})

all: 
    @echo original str: ${SRC_VAR}
    @echo substitution: ${TEST1_VAR}
```

This is the output:

```
original str: test string for variable manipulation.

substitution:
```

The output should be:

```
original str: My test string for variable manipulation.

substitution: My test string foo variable manipulation.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution command is `subst`, not `subset`.